# jQuery Next With Span & Input

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<span class="xyz">Test</span><input type="text" class="hello">
<span class="xyz">Test</span><input type="text" class="hello">
<span class="xyz">Test</span><input type="text" class="hello">
```

I want to automatically focus on the next input:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.hello', function() {
    $(this).next('input').focus();
});
```

If I remove the  code, it works fine. But when the  code is there, it does not. Thoughts?

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/AHGu2/1/ Maybe there's something else causing your problem?

Comment: No. Your example isn't working for me either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.next('input')`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) won't work since the element following the `<input>` is a `<span>`.

Try [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.hello', function() {
    if ($(this).nextAll('input').length)
        $(this).nextAll('input')[0].focus();
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Xp2Vn/1/).